# Watch all Less Files but only compile one main one

Tags: javascript, webpack, phoenix-framework, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

So I downloaded a theme that has a bunch of less files but there is a main one that imports the others in the correct order. It came with a gulp file that watches any .less file but recompiles only the one that imports all the others. It looks like so:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
 return gulp.src(Paths.LESS_TOOLKIT_SOURCES)
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(autoprefixer())
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write(Paths.HERE))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

My webpackconfig so far looks like the following:

```
// Things I still need to do:

// 1) Add uglifier plugin for minification

var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var cssnext = require('cssnext');
var cssimport = require('postcss-import');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false;

module.exports = {
devtool: 'eval',
entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './app/index'
],
stylePath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'style'),
postcss: function () {
  return [
    cssimport({
      path: './app/style/index.css',
      onImport: function (files) {
        files.forEach(this.addDependency)
      }.bind(this)
    }),
    cssnext()
  ]
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  cssFilename: 'style.css',
  publicPath: '/static/'
},
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', {
    allChunks: true
  }),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
  },
  {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: isProd ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?  modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss') : 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss'
},
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loader: "style!css!less"
}]
},
resolve: {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname),
  extensions: [
    '',
    '.js',
    '.css'
  ],
  modulesDirectories: [
    'app',
    'node_modules'
  ]
}
};
```

I am trying to accomplish the the same thing but with webpack. I have installed and setup the less-loader like the guide says but it tries to compile all of the files. Is there a way to set it up like the gulp file that will watch any file but only compile a specific file? I have this working in brunch when working in Phoenix but I trying to switch brunch out with webpack for phoenix.

In brunch I just told it to ignore the folder with the less files and then had the main less file outside that directory so brunch would only compile the main less file and import the others.

Comment: You'll need to add your webpack config to this question in order for it to be answerable.

Comment: @spender i have added it. Thank you